# Erlang get the nth element

Tags: erlang

I'd like to get the nth element.

```erlang
-module(lab02).
-export([functionGetnth/2]).

functionGetnth([], _N) ->
    {error, no_such_element};
functionGetnth([H|_T], 1) -> H;
functionGetnth([H|T], N) when N > 1 ->
    functionGetnth([H|T], N-1).
```

How can I delete the Head while the Head isn't the nth position?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Paste the code and format it neatly into a code block instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already such function in the standard library, see [lists:nth/2](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#nth-2).

If you insist on making your own, you need to recurse only on the tail (`T`) in your third clause, thus discarding the head (`H`), i.e.:

```
functionGetNth(T, N-1).
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-module(lab02).
-export([functionGetNth/2]).

functionGetNth([], _N) ->
    {error, no_such_element};
functionGetNth([H|_], 1) -> H;
functionGetNth([_|T], N) when N > 1 ->
    functionGetNth(T, N-1).
```